# spring data jpa repository: update only certain columns or all non null columns

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

So I have an entity:

```
public class Test extends BaseEntity {
    private String title;
    private Double passMark;

    @Convert(converter = DurationToStringConverter.class)
    private Duration duration;

    @ManyToOne
    private User createdBy;

    @ManyToOne
    private User updatedBy;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Question> questions;
    ...
}
```

And I have a small form which allows to modify title, passmark and duration.

When this form is submitted I want to only update these fields.
Is there a way to do it without @Query annotation, i.e. only using Spring Data Repository's magic interface methods?

Comment: Do you really think updating two additional columns will have a significant impact on performance? It won't. Actually, not updating them could have a negative overall impact on performance, because statements would be less reused.

Comment: @Nomad: is this because you don't want to load the entity before updating it?

Comment: @Augusto yes, do not want to have 2 queries

Comment: @JBNizet I do not want to fetch entity, update two entries and save it, I just want to update two properties of the entity with one query

Comment: Then use a query. But you'll lose what makes JPA simple to use. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries